# Free .NET Windows Controls Library?

Tags: .net, winforms

Does anyone know any good and free .NET Windows Controls Library

Comment: https://github.com/WithoutCaps/LimitlessUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [Component Factory](http://www.componentfactory.com/) has got some.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best component vendor in the market, [Developer Express](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/WebRegistration60/), has some great ones. These should start you off; though any additional components you get with a paid subscription are certainly well worth it.

Comment: I would like to point out that they have over 60 of their controls freely available.

Comment: This is [no longer accurate](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q443017/devexpress-60-free-controls)

Answer (score 2):

On [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/Project/ProjectDirectory.aspx?TagName=Controls,Windows%20Forms) there a some nice ones.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked Ascend.NET.  Well documented, excellent designer support, source code included.

Answer (score 1):

Mono [WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms) lags behind Microsoft, but includes many of the familiar controls. If you are ready to try something different, Mono has other [Gui ToolKits](http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits).

Comment: I could be wrong be he probably just meant some library on top of standard WinForms, not completely new toolkit.